# Using Qt QWebPage in a Windows QtService

Tags: qt, windows-7, qtwebkit

I am using QtService to write a web page thumbnail rendering service.  Is it possible to include sufficient of the Gui libraries to keep QtWebKit happy without running into the restriction on interactive services?

I have the websnap sample from [websnap.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/graphics-dojo/blobs/master/websnap/websnap.cpp) and this somehow convinces the QWebPage component that a Gui is available without actually displaying the widget.  When I try to duplicate the environment in the service it complains that there in no gui for the widget.
I strongly suspect that QtService and QWebPage are fundamentally incompatible but have not yet given up hope that there is a workaround.

I am not even sure what it is that the websnap sample does that keeps QWebPage happy (is it just because its linked with the Gui library?)

I am very new to the Qt library so the answer may be obvious to someone with more experience.

Thanks, 
Andy

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify that the Qt documentation demonstrates that the QWebPage can be created in a "Widget-less environment" but that precise method fails in the service with the error "QWidget: cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althought QtWebKit can work in **headless** environment (without any visible widgets), it still requires graphics libraries etc to be present and functional. Otherwise, how would it compute font metrics, render the text, and so on? Thus, you always need QtGui.

PS: I wrote the websnap example :)